# Inspecting a .exe to understand with what version of Visual C++ it was built

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is there a way to check what version of Visual C++ was used to build a given .exe?

I know that if the .exe uses dynamic link with CRT that is easy: I can just use Dependency Walker and read the MSVCRxx.DLL version, e.g. a dependency on MSVCR90.DLL means that the .exe is built with Visual C++ 2008 i.e. VC9; but what about the case of static linking with CRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible check linker version in Depends.exe, is almost identical as VisualC++ version.

In lower view in Dependency Walker, select column **Linker Ver**.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting article on MSDN by Matt Pietrek:

[Inside Windows: An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

The fields of interests are `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32/64::MajorLinkerVersion` and `MinorLinkerVersion`. They are almost identical to Visual C++ version (e.g "10" and "0" for VC10).

(I think these are the fields that Dependency Walker uses for the *Linker Ver* column in its user interface.)

Comment: Correct, but as specified (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) these fields are Optionals. These are just informational flags, nothing more. The Windows loader does not care about these fields.